# Disk options for Azure Container instances

Tags: azure-container-service

Is there a way to pick disk type when creating ACIs? For example choose to use SSDs for better performance?

I don't see any mentions of any disk options in [documentation for `az container create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-create)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure Container Instances offers the fastest and simplest way to run a
>   container in Azure, without having to manage any virtual machines and
>   without having to adopt a higher-level service.

It seems you cannot select which disk type to run the container, it's decided by Azure. You just can select the CPU and memory. For more details, see [Azure Container Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-overview).

Comment: You can mount an Azure Files share to ACI. see my answer for more detail.

Comment: @MattM Does Azure File Share have any effection on Disk type?!

Comment: You can only mount Azure Files shares to Linux containers. Through some magic handled by Microsoft you dont have to worry about the file format

Comment: @MattM Are you sure the Azure File Share only can mount to Linux? And if so, what is the relationship between the Disk type and the Linux?! Please understand the question carefully!

Answer (score 2):

By default, Azure Container Instances are stateless. If the container is restarted, crashes, or stops, all of its state is lost. To persist state beyond the lifetime of the container, you must mount a volume from an external store. Azure Container Instances can mount an Azure file share created with Azure Files. Azure Files offers fully managed file shares hosted in Azure Storage. Using an Azure file share with Azure Container Instances provides file-sharing features similar to using an Azure file share with Azure virtual machines.

See documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files